# Arduino + Sim900 + MySql connection problem

Tags: mysql, arduino, sim900

I'm doing a project where I must do a query to a mysql server with the Sim900 module throught Arduino. Let me explain what I have, so that you can help me:

- Arduino Uno (original version)
- Sim900 module (https://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B07FS34P84/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
- 5V/2A Power Supply Adapter for Sim900 (https://www.amazon.es/gp/product/B07DX11WJJ/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
- Windows Server 2012 with Static Ip (xxx.xxx.xx.xx), with a MySql Server that allows external connections (with an extern computer or smartphone, I can access the db)

First of all, I tried to do a query with the GChrome, like http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:3306/connect.php but this didn't worked. Then, I downloaded XAMPP and connected Apache and MySql. At that time, I writted in the Chrome search bar: http://localhost/connect.php and it said: Connected successfully so, at that moment I knew that I connected to the db.

So, I tried to connect with AT commands: First of all, I connected with the APN

```
AT+CSTT= "airtelnet.es", "vodafone", "vodafone"
```

and then I tried to connect with TCP to the server

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","xxx.xx.xxx.xxx","3306"
```

At this moment, the Serial Monitor gave me some errors and special characters.

Can someone help me with this?, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do. Are you using sim900 for gprs as internet connection for Arduino? Do your arduino has shield for LAN cable.

If so, your xampp mysql should work as API server. Arduino will call url to send data, mysql is just internal job of server, no directly connection with arduino.